# Selenium fails to run program headless

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, chromium

I'm attempting to run a Headless selenium session via Chrome Web Driver in python.
The code I have here should be able to run it headless mode, but it runs headed and I don't get any error codes. I'm running Windows 10, Python 3.7.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Comment: place "options.add_argument("--headless")" before "driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)"

Comment: It's because you are already instantiate the driver thru "driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)" without telling that it should be headless.

Answer (score 0):

`options.addArguments("headless");`

Try without -- before headless and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this as well:

```
options.headless = True
```